# Global Country Index for Insurance

Tags: interest-rates, index, econometrics, macro-economics, insurance

I am trying to create a global country index for insurance. So this would be insurance by country. Anybody who is an expert in econometrics can give me some guidance on how to do this? How would I go around creating a methodology, how do I test the variables to include or not etc.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by insurance by country?

Comment: What I mean is I want to rank countries by the size of the insurance industry, the growth potential of the insurance industry in the country etc. That's basically it. That's what I am looking for. What variables should I be looking at to generate this? Thanks.